# Integration of third party subscription services in ios app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Before going further I want to clarify that this is not program related question. I'm unable to find proper docs or guidelines for my problem hence I'm asking the question here.

My problem is that I am working on a application which is a platform for quitting the smoking habit. We offer text and video content to our users on subscription basis. We are already using the Apple's IAP for this purpose. Now I want to know if I can integrate third party subscription service in my application such as PayPal or Google Pay, etc. The application comes under health category and also it delivers only text and video content to user. If yes then what are the different methods I can use?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#person-to-person-services Particularly 3.1.3(d)

Comment: @Paulw11 we do offer one on one coaching functionality besides that, our application's main functionality is day wise content which is text and video given to user for continuous 7 days, where 1st day is free and other 6 days are available on subscription. So I'm wondering if I can provide third party subscription to the user.

Comment: You could use probably use an alternate payment for one on one coaching but not for the text and video content